# Java, handling variable arguments and referring to object created basing on them (?)

Tags: java, loops, foreach

It will be my first question here, I used site a lot, but for the very first time I haven't found an answer. I try to port to java some code found online, originally written in python, it is my first time I use those 'fancy' loops and function with variable arguments, so I have some problems connected to those topics.
Also I am aware of poorly titled question, but I really had no idea how to title it.

I have a class like this:

```
public class Keyboard {
Keyboard(String... rows){
    double y=0;
    for(String row : rows){
        double x=0;
        /** For-each loop is applicable for arrays and Iterable.  
           * String is not an array. It holds array of characters but it is not an array itself. 
            *String does not implement interface Iterable too.
            *If you want to use for-each loop for iteration over characters into the string you have to say:
            */
        for(char letter : row.toCharArray()){                
            if(letter!=' '){
                letter : new Point2D.Double(x,y);
                letter : System.out.println("Punkt " + letter + "   x: " + x + "   y: " + y);
                //to print it out like in python sauce, i guess I would have to overwrite tostring() 
            }
            x+=0.5;
        }  
        y++;
     }
}
```

and then main like this:

```
public class test {
public static void main(String[] args){
Keyboard qwerty = new Keyboard("Q W E R T Y U I O P",
                               " A S D F G H J K L ",
                               "   Z X C V B N M   ");
Point W = qwerty['W']; //this line is wrong
}
```

I understand that keyboard takes in that case 3 strings as arguments, and so on, but i have no idea how to, hmm, refer from main to particullar letter created in Keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `qwerty['W']` because `qwerty` isn't an array, and Java only allows array indexing on actual arrays.  There's no Java equivalent to Python's `__getitem__` method, so you can't make other classes support array-like access.  You'll need to write an ordinary method to do the lookup instead.

As far as the variadic parameter (`String... rows`), that's just a fancy way of passing an array.  When you *call* the `Keyboard` constructor, you can write multiple strings in the parentheses, and they'll automatically be made into an array.  Within the *implementation* of the `Keyboard` constructor, it's the same as if the argument were `String[] rows`.

It's not entirely clear what the `Keyboard` constructor is supposed to do, but if your goal is to be able to look up coordinates for letter keys, the simplest way to do that is by having a `Map` field in the class:

```
public class Keyboard {
  // ...
  private final Map<Character, Point> keyPositions = new HashMap<>();
  // ...
}
```

Then, in the constructor, you can populate it with entries for each letter:

```
for (char letter : row.toCharArray()) {
  // ...
  keyPositions.put(letter, new Point2D.Double(x, y));
  // ...
}
```

Your function for looking up a letter's position can just get the entry from the array:

```
public Point getPosition(char letter) {
  return keyPositions.get(letter);
}
```

and instead of `qwerty['W']` you'd write `qwerty.getPosition('W')`.

Comment: Also, the OP is passing a single string literal to the Keyboard constructor, where I think OP means to pass in an array, with each letter as a separate element. Your answer doesn't cover that part and I think it's probably pertinent.

Comment: OP is passing *three* string literals to the constructor, representing the three rows of letters on a keyboard, and the constructor calls the parameter `rows` and has a loop over the strings.  So I think that's intentional.

Comment: I'm just puzzled by the occurrences of `letter :` as a label, and the allocation of a new point object without assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Oh right you are, damn lazy eyes. Yeah, I'm puzzled over `letter :` myself.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the right place for me to reply.
I was not aware of such thing as hasmap, which is very helpful in that situation. You perfectly undestand my porblem, and helped me a lot, now I can easily calculate distances from letters and so on, f.e.
`System.out.println(qwerty.getPosition('W').distance(qwerty.getPosition('F')));`

Also, I still don't fuly understand usage of that "letter:" thing, so that is why you are puzzled guys.
About:  *the allocation of a new point object without assigning it to a variable*, what do you exacly mean and what should I do?
@Wyzard